# Unsupported depth of input image

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, matplotlib

How to keep the RGB Color of the image?

I'm showing the image using this code

```
img = cv2.imread('IMG_0460.jpg')
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
```

The next line im trying to keep the RGB Color while resizing the image

```
resize = tf.image.resize(img, (224,224))
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(resize.numpy().astype(int),cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
```

But I get this error when I'm executing the code before:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-184-d6c1e44056bc> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 resize = tf.image.resize(img, (224,224))
----> 2 plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(resize.numpy().astype(int),cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
      3 plt.show()

error: OpenCV(4.7.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.simd_helpers.hpp:94: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'cv::impl::{anonymous}::CvtHelper<VScn, VDcn, VDepth, sizePolicy>::CvtHelper(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int) [with VScn = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<3, 4>; VDcn = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<3, 4>; VDepth = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<0, 2, 5>; cv::impl::{anonymous}::SizePolicy sizePolicy = cv::impl::<unnamed>::NONE; cv::InputArray = const cv::_InputArray&; cv::OutputArray = const cv::_OutputArray&]'
> Unsupported depth of input image:
>     'VDepth::contains(depth)'
> where
>     'depth' is 4 (CV_32S)
```

Comment: Have a look at tensorflow docs. tf.image.resize returns floating point image, which is 32 bit.  .astype(int) is 32 bit signed integer. (CV_32S). I don't know python/numpy syntax well, but you could try .astype(uint8) or similar.

Comment: you should turn your comments into answers more often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tensorflow `resize` function changes the datatype of the array to float which is not expected by cv2. We should have to convert it to unsigned-integer that is well supported by cv2.

Below is a working code snippet.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("IMG_0460.jpg")
resize = tf.image.resize(img, (224, 224))
color_converted = cv2.cvtColor(resize.numpy().astype(np.uint8), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

plt.imshow(color_converted)
```

I would strongly suggest to use `cv2.resize()` if you are using tensorflow only for the sake of image resizing.